# Is it possible to convert a windows assembly to mono?

Tags: .net, mono, assemblies

I have a closed source assembly (isn't obfuscated or anything like that), but I was wondering if there was an application that will take that assembly and convert it to mono (especially for use on linux). Is this automatic or do I need to do something. I haven't done any mono... ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that everything required by the assembly is supported by Mono, you shouldn't have to do *anything* - it should already be binary compatible. That's one of the points of IL :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Mono Migration Analyzer](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) to make sure that it is Mono compatible. If so, any .net assembly may be used a Mono based project. If it's an executable, test with `mono myapp.exe` from shell.

Comment: Thanks, that tells me my entire app works on mono, just to test it. That speeds it up a LOT.